# smtplib email does not send, script keeps running with no error message

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to learn smtplib through a video tutorial and this code should successfully send an email, but when I try to run it, the script keeps running and does not stop unless I manually stop it. Any ideas for what I would need to change for it to send the email successfully?

```
import smtplib

my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
password = "password"

connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
                    to_addrs=my_email,
                    msg="Subject:Hello\n\nHello")
connection.close()
```

(I have replaced my email and password for the purposes of this question)

Answer (score 1):

ok I figured it out

I needed to set up the smtplib.SMTP object as

```
smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com:587")
```